# iOS POST JSON Echo Disallowed Key Characters

Tags: php, ios, json, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dictionary setObject:self.uniqueKey forKey:@"unique"];


[dictionary setObject:groupArr forKey:@"addressbook"];



if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dictionary]){

    NSURL *uploadPath=[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

   }
```

I am tring to post this dictionary.The `groupArr` consist of Addressbook Contacts.But its is giving me Echo message form server `Echo Disallowed Key Charatcers`I am not getting y it is throwing this error